# Drupal - Add a relation via Entity Form

Tags: drupal, relation

I have created a relation called user-advisor relation between a user and a content type I named Advisor on my Drupal 7 site. I have also created an entityform type called Advisor where I have created an entity reference field that has a list of all of the Advisor content types. What I want to be able to do is have the user submit this form and when it is submitted I want to create a new user-advisor relation with the user and the selected advisor, I am curious as to what would be the best way to do this and if there is a module to do so. I have looked into the Relation Add module but I am not sure if its functionality is what I need or how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[Relation](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) this module and use [hook_entity_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7). You need to check documentation though, because I don't really remember exact code, that you need to use, to create relation. But from what I remember it was pretty much straightforward.

Comment: Ok I am somewhat new to making modules so I am trying to figure this out. I have an entityform type called add support that has a entity reference field that has a list of custom content types I created called advisors. Every time this form is submitted I want to create my relation but before I can start creating this relation I need to be able to access this forms information. Which would be the best hook function for this? I was thinking  [hook_entityform_type_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7) but im not sure.

Comment: I am not sure if I really get what you want to do. But, if you are new to creating modules, there is also another way. Rules. You can use rules together with Relation, and this should give you enough tools to do, what you want to do. (You will have different events for entities and forms)